# How to implement the ACID model for a database?

Tags: mysql, database

How do Igo about achieving the ACID properties for my database - 
A- Atomicity, C- Consistency, I- Isolation, D- Durability. 
Database system being used - MySql.

Comment: ACID is something that the database provides for you, not really something that you have to implement. You can use ACID to build a reliable application.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well ACID is not a model that you can implement, but rather a set of rules that a database server must conform to in order to be able to handle transactions in a safe way.

MySQL is not an ACID compliant database server by design, but if you use the **InnoDB** storage engine for your tables (or better as your database server default storage engine by setting the `default-storage-engine` option to `InnoDB` (see [default-storage-engine option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine))), you will be able to perform transaction-safe operations on your database.

I recommend you set InnoDB as your default storage engine because it is important that you **don't mix operations on tables with different storage engines within a single transaction** (InnoDB and MyISAM tables for example). Otherwise you might corrupt your data because you won't be able to rollback all your operations if you rollback your transaction.

That said, how do you ensure that your operations are ACID compliant? Well simply by **grouping operations within transactions** to go **from one consistent state of your data to another**, and commit at the end if everything went well, or rollback if something went wrong. To achieve this you need to tell the database server when your transaction start by issuing a `START TRANSACTION` statement, and when your transaction end with a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statement.

It is generally a good practice to disable the autocommit mode at the beginning of your scripts by using the `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` command, although it's not mandatory since the `START TRANSACTION` command actually disable the autocommit mode.

Also keep in mind that some statements issue an implicit `COMMIT` command (basically all DDL statements, and some others, see [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html)).

You might also be interested in reading about the differences from standard SQL with regard to treatment of transactions in MySQL [Transactions and Atomic Operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the innoDB-engine in MySQL, create a proper database schema including foreign keys, use transactions for related queries, use servergrade hardware and let the database do it's job.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: Oh... thanks. One more question though .... how can the database manage atomicity in case of hardware failure?
Suppose i have two queries. QUERY 1, QUERY 2, what happens when there is a hardware failure between these two queries?

Comment: It's about related queries. Query nr. 2 will never be executed, that's why you need transactions if these queries are related: If the first query is part of the same transaction, the entire transaction is never committed and your database is still correct (ROLLBACK). Without a transaction, you have a corrupt database.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you properly it is not your task. It is a task of MySql developers (Oracle). 
If database server support ACID you can use it by choose correct isolation level and use transactions (impicit or explicit).